# catch hyper link clicking with javascript(or jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user clicks a link in his inbox, I want to mark the message related to the link as `seen`.

SO has this feature as well,
If someone replies to my post, SO shows something happend to my post.
After I click the inbox message and visit the post, SO no longer shows notification mark.

I guess it's too expensive to test if visiting user of a question has an inbox message every time a user visits any question page.
I wonder if it's possible to catch `clicking-link` in the inbox page, so that I can send ajax request under the hood to mark the message `as seen`

Hope my questions are clear.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Hint: Google something like jQuery handle link click

Comment: is this explicit to stackoverflow? or just that you want to handle a link being clicked?

Comment: "*it's too expensive to test if visiting user of a question has an inbox message every time a user visits any question page*" - Why do you guess that? And of course you have to do that in order to show him the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom data attribute to each message you click. I'm not sure how your displaying messages, but for this example we'll use a span:

```
<span class="message">Some Message</span>
```

And the JS:

```
$(".message").click(function() {
    $(this).data("visited", true);
});
```

Then you can check spans to see if they've been visited. If you still want to do the AJAX call, you can simply add an AJAX event inside the click handler as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some sort of 'status' field on your messages table to differentiate between 'Read' and 'Unread'.

If you are asking how to efficiently store the number of unread messages in an inbox without running a query on every page load, this can easily be accomplished by setting a $_SESSION variable:

```
$_SESSION['unread_messages'] = 2;
```

After this variable is set, you can periodically check (every 5 minutes or so) to keep this up to date within a reasonable window. When a message is clicked and read, you will subtract 1 from this value or re-query the number of unread messages.

If you are asking about how to update the database and UI, there are 2 main ways you would go about doing this. It will depend on what currently happens in your script when a user clicks on a message. Do you make an AJAX request to load the message, or does the link take the user to a different page?

If you make an AJAX request when a message is clicked, simply have the script that is called in the AJAX request also mark the message as read (in the database), and use JavaScript to make any UI updates to the current page (such as removing bold text on the message that was clicked).

If clicking on a message redirects to a different page where the entire message is displayed, you can mark the message as read in the database when that page loads.